# Can Luis service created in WestUS region query by users in Asia and Australia?

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I created a LUIS service in westUS region, and its endpoint is  https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/...... If I use it in my bot, can any users from any regions including Asia and Australia access to the Luis service? 
In addition, I can't assign key to Asia region. But it's said possible according to this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-reference-regions

Answer (score 1):

> I created a LUIS service in westUS region, and its endpoint is https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/...... If I use it in my bot, can any users from any regions including Asia and Australia access to the Luis service?

If you create and publish your LUIS app to **North America Regions**, the users from other regions (such as Asia and Australia etc) can also access to that LUIS app.

> I can't assign key to Asia region.

In ["Publishing regions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions), we can find: *LUIS apps created on https://www.luis.ai can be published to all endpoints **except** the European and Australian regions.*

On the other hand, based on my test, it seems that we can not publish the LUIS apps created on au.luis.ai to Asia, North America etc Regions.

Do a test and can reproduce same issue:

1) can not assign the LUIS key of LUIS service (in **australiaeast**) to app created on https://www.luis.ai

2) can [assign the LUIS key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-manage-keys#assign-endpoint-key) of LUIS service (in **southeastasia**) to app created on https://www.luis.ai

[image]